# Can $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 + (-1)^n }{1.25^n} $ be split into two?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 + (-1)^n }{1.25^n} $$ be split into two so that it could be solved without the comparison test?

I am thinking of splitting the sum into to: the first one will be a convergent series, whereas the second one could be solved using the ratio test.

Comment: Hint. The numerator is positive and bounded by $3$ so it's easy to compare to a convergent geometric series. Why try to avoid comparison?

Comment: @EthanBolker I see, thank you. I would, nevertheless, like to answer the same exercise thinking of a different approach, just to practice my "sequences and series skills" =)

Comment: $1.25^n>2$ when $n\ge 4$, and $1.25^{n+1}>1.25^n \forall n\ge1$

Comment: Also the exact value of the series could be found with separation of summation into odd and even $n$.

Comment: You can split if you like. If both $\sum\frac 2{1.25^n}$ and $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{1.25^n}$ converge, then so does the given series (and it converges to the sum of the two)

Answer (score 0):

If $$\sum{f}=\sum a\pm\sum b$$
where $\sum a$ and $\sum b$ are convergent, then $\sum f$ is convergent too. Apply this to your sereis by splitting it to:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2+(-1)^n}{1.25^n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{1.25^n}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)}{1.25^n}}$$

$1.25^n>2$ when $n\ge 4$, and $1.25^{n+1}>1.25^n \forall n\ge1$.

Thus Ratio Test makes$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1.25^n}$$
convergent.

With regards to the other half$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)}{1.25^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1.25^{2n}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1.25^{2n-1}}$$

Showing they are both convergent will resolve your question.